AWS Amplify React App Deployment giving false 404 in console when refreshing paging
I am testing a deployment  of a Web App on AWS Amplify and am getting a false 404 reply in console even though the page is showing correctly when you trigger a refresh from the browser.
Format for all routes show absolute path such as /services/
<NavLink to='/services/'><li className='p-2 hover:text-blue-500'>Services</li></NavLink>
when page loads for the first time the url shows
https://main.d1ccz03uoktudf.amplifyapp.com/services/ and the is no 404 error in console, however if you refresh the page the error will show but  the page is still showing correctly.
I updated all routes and Link to items to ahve the absoulte paths for each page /services/ /contact/ etc... The error appears to be false as the page is loading but trying to find a way to fix the false 404.
